# Probability generating function

Tags: probability

What does this mean: 
Find discrete multivariate distributions which have explicit formula for their joint probability  generating function?
Please if anyone understand this question , just give an example or expression for me!

Comment: They're probably assuming you understand the terminology at the point your at. Re read over your material looking for the key terms in the question.

Comment: It is not clear. If i have multivariate poisson distribution , should i find their joint pgf? . I don't have materials for this. It is a general question ,not refer to my materials or notes. I really confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you know what an MGF is. So, looking at this question, you will have to find the MGFS of multiple variate distributions.

For example,
Lets take the Poisson distribution.
1. It is univariate
2. It is discrete
and has an MGF

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution

MGF can be calculated by E(e^tx) for any distribution.

Comment: :Thanks for your answer. that was helpful.